# why can't i use contentType as application/pdf in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

While i m doing like the following ,i m getting  msg like :

> failed to load pdf

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Account"  sidebar="false"
        showHeader="false" contentType="application/pdf">
<apex:pageBlock title="Contacts">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Account.contacts}" var="contact">
<apex:column value="{!contact.name}"/>
<apex:column value="{!contact.MailingCity}"/>
<apex:column value="{!contact.phone}"/>
</apex:pageBlocktable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be rather

> apex:page renderAs="pdf"

full spec for renderAs [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_page.htm)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer provided by @BigBallOfMud, you'll want to look at [Best Practices for Rendering PDFs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_additional_render_pdf.htm) as `<apex pageBlock>` and `<apex pageBlockTable>` are both listed as * **Components That Are Unsafe to Use in a PDF**. *

Answer (score 1):

There are differences in Visualforce rendering when using renderAs and ContentType:-

when we set ***renderAs = PDF,*** it triggers Visualforce engine to generate PDF from page's resultant HTML. In plain words, this triggers conversion of HTML to PDF data (binary)

when we set ***contentType = application/pdf***, then it only impacts the html response's HTTP header, which is used by browser to display files according to their mime-type. This is mostly used for mime-types wherein browser can open the file in appropriate application for e.g. Ms-Excel etc. In plain words, it just renders content in appropriate client application (driven by browser)